# How can I configure EAGetMail DLL options to make date search work?

Tags: vb.net, email, pop3

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for taking the time reading my question.

I have this scenario: I'm using `EAGetMail` DLL to retrieve emails from a POP3 e-mail server. I have used an example given on the website and so far so good; I can get all the emails from my inbox.

My problem arises when I try to use the data filters that the DLL provides, in order to not get all the emails in the inbox, just a few, using a certain data range.

The code that I'm using for this purpose is the following:

```
Dim oClient As New MailClient("TryIt")
    
oClient.Connect(oServer)
    
Dim options As GetMailInfosOptionType
options = options Or GetMailInfosOptionType.DateRange
options = options Or GetMailInfosOptionType.OrderByDateTime
        
oClient.GetMailInfosParam.Reset()
oClient.GetMailInfosParam.GetMailInfosOptions = options
        
oClient.GetMailInfosParam.DateRange.SINCE = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)
oClient.GetMailInfosParam.DateRange.BEFORE = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```

Theoretically this should retrieve only the emails within last four days from today, but it is not working. Everytime I execute the code I get every e-mail from my inbox.

Has someone faced something similar to this?

Comment: This question is answered by the documentation. No one should be asking questions without reading the documentation first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney after being in this forum for some months now, and reading a lot of your comments and replies, I think that no one should be having yout attitude towards people that are only looking for help when they found themselves stuck on a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence on [this page](https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/sdk/?ct=mailclient_getmailinfosparam), regarding the `MailClient.GetMailInfosParam` property, says that POP3 is not supported:

> Search email on IMAP4 Server and MS Exchange Server. It doesn't
> support POP3 protocol.

Comment: To be clear, the `GetMailInfos` method does support the POP3 protocol but the `GetMailInfosParam` property will be ignored in that case, so the reported behaviour of info for all mail being returned is exactly what should be expected.

Comment: That is right. I found the documentation for the `GetMailnfosParam` directly from the page where it is explained how to retrieve all emails (both for POP3 and IMAP) so I assumed that the information could be used for any of those technologies.